# How to get Label text of UITableView Cell using Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I want to make simple UITabelView. I registered it's cell with my custom class which named as backgroundviewcell. I want to get Label of the selected cell. I tried many times but the output is coming nil value. I have also tried solution from stack overflow but it does not work for me. This is my cellForRowAt indexPath code :

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> backgroundViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soundElementalcell") as! backgroundViewCell


    let imageNames = sections[indexPath.section].images[indexPath.row]

    cell.Labeltittle.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    cell.Labeltittle.textColor = UIColor(hex : 0x90BA27)
    cell.LabelDetail.text = sections[indexPath.section].detail[indexPath.row]
    //cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
    //cell.isHighlighted = false

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.iconview.image = UIImage(named: imageNames)

     return cell
}
```

This is my didSelectRowAt indexPath code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {


    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

    celltext = currentCell.textLabel!.text
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPlayer", sender: self)
}
```

and my Segue Method is :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPlayer" {

        let playerVC = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController
        playerVC.trackName = (celltext)! as String


    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't. You should get it from your tableview data source

Comment: Use `indexPathForSelectedRow` to access your array element

Comment: please all var in lowerCamelCase - because all classes always in UpperCamelCase

Comment: Please show us your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath methods and also tell us why you want to get Label from Cell.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @muesha.

Comment: This is my method : 

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> backgroundViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soundElementalcell") as! backgroundViewCell

        
        cell.Labeltittle.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
     
         return cell
    }           Actually i have 5 sections and in all section there is diff. type of array elements(string). Thats why i'm using text label of the cell for the next view controller to play my sound file. @Usman Javed

Comment: @Chetan you should post your code to your question. Not to the comments area

Comment: @Leo Dabus..I added my code. u can check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of accessing the text from the cell's `label` you need to access the array that you have used to fill the `tableView's` cell data.

So you need to use `UITableViewDelegate` method `didSelectRowAtindexPath` and access the array that you are using with your tableView methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
    //Access the array that you have used to fill the tableViewCell
    print(yourArray[indexPath.row])
}
```

**Note:** Once confirm that `TableView` `delegate` is properly connected with your `ViewController` so that it will call `didSelectRowAt` method when you select cell.

**Edit:** If you want to pass the data then try like this way.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPlayer", sender: indexPath) //Pass indexPath as sender instead of self
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPlayer" {

        let playerVC = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        playerVC.trackName = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]       
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i have 5 sections and in all section there is diff. type of array elements(string). Thats why i'm using text label of the cell for the next view controller to play my sound file.

Comment: @Chetan Check the edited answer once to pass the data

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code is working. You saved my life. :) @ Nirav D

Comment: Accepted you answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is working for me:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! YourCellType
    let labelContent = cell.labelToAccess.text
}
```

First line creates an instance of your cell type (or standard cell, not my case).

The second saves the content of your label (labelToAccess in this case) in a constant.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this 'Swift 4' -**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let currentCellTxt = yourTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as? YourCustomTableViewCell

    print(currentCellTxt?.lblYourName?.text)   // 'lblYourName' that you defined in your  'YourCustomTableViewCell'

}
```

Comment: Um...you already have indexPath in the function parameter of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`...why would you even bother getting indexPath again? I am border line wanting to down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set any text for textLabel. Hence it returns nil value.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> backgroundViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soundElementalcell") as! backgroundViewCell


    let imageNames = sections[indexPath.section].images[indexPath.row]

    cell.Labeltittle.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    cell.Labeltittle.textColor = UIColor(hex : 0x90BA27)
    cell.LabelDetail.text = sections[indexPath.section].detail[indexPath.row]
    //cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
    //cell.isHighlighted = false

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.iconview.image = UIImage(named: imageNames)

     return cell
}

In didSelectRow func try to get value from Labeltittle.text not from textLabel.text

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {


    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

    celltext = currentCell.Labeltittle.text
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPlayer", sender: self)
}
```